# Is it an error for a class to call an abstractmethod from its superclass? Why does PEP 544 say it is?

Tags: python, protocols, pep, abstract-methods

I'm currently studying [PEP544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) to see whether type hinting protocols can help me in my development workflow.

In the section *Explicitly Declaring Implementation*, there is some code which I have rewritten as follows:

```
from typing import Protocol
from abc import abstractmethod

class PColor(Protocol):
  @abstractmethod
  def draw(self) -> str: ... 

  def complex_method(self) -> int:
    return 1+1

class NiceColor(PColor):
  def draw(self) -> str:
    return "deep blue"

class BadColor(PColor):
  def draw(self) -> str:
    return super().draw()
```

According to the PEP, the line `return super().draw()` should throw an error as there is no default implementation in `PColor`.

I've tried running this with `python test.py` and `mypy --strict test.py`, and both of them run without throwing an error.

Is there a mistake in the PEP, or am I missing something?

Comment: The documentation [for the abstractmethod decorator itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) seems to contradict the PEP. I don't see a way in principle that a static type checker would distinguish between `def draw(self) -> str: ...`, or `def draw(self) -> str: pass`, and an "actual" default implementation. Especially since there are perfectly reasonable scenarios where the default implementation *should* just `return None`.

Comment: Hmm... it sounds like I may have uncovered a mistake then?

Comment: You're talking about the part where it says `return super().draw()  # Error, no default implementation`, right? I think the PEP is trying to say that's a *logical* error, rather than trying to say that this will throw an exception or saying that type checkers should report it as an error.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica that would have been the first time the word "Error" was used like that in a programming context. Why not just use something like "poor practice" ?

Comment: It'd be far from the first time. (Also, "poor practice" would be a much weaker claim. They're saying it's *wrong*, not just a bad idea. Sure, it might not throw an exception, but "wrong" and "throws an exception" are different things. Plenty of perfectly correct code throws exceptions, and plenty of wrong code doesn't.)

Comment: Still seems fishy to me